# How to deal: conan & cmake setup does not print stdout on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, conan

### Setup

I have the project [github SageStore](https://stackoverflow.com),  branch 64_create_mainwindow

I'm trying to configure project on my Windows 11 machine using VS Code as an IDE.

So, when I'm building my project I'm like

```bash
conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing -s build_type=Debug
cmake .. --preset conan-debug
cmake --build .
```

And then I just go and run the bad guy:

```bash
cd build\Client 
.\SageStoreClient.exe
```

But unless the main.cpp where I do something like this:

```cpp
void initSpdlog()
{
    // Create color multi threaded logger
    auto console = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("console");

    // Set the log level
    console->set_level(spdlog::level::info);

    // Set the pattern
    console->set_pattern("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%e] [%^%l%$] %v");

    // Flush the log entries automatically
    console->flush_on(spdlog::level::info);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "stdout works fine" << std::endl;
    initSpdlog();
    SPDLOG_INFO("SageStoreClient started"); // Make sure you're using the macro SPDLOG_INFO, not the function
}
```

The program prints nothing.

### Debugging

#### 1. Test in Qt Creator

When I use Qt Creator to setup project and run it. It gives me fine output for stdout inside Qt Creator (no matter if it's output window or external terminal).

###### Why?

I figured out that it's because Projects >> Run >>  `Add build library search in PATH` flag

Or `<value type="bool" key="RunConfiguration.UseLibrarySearchPath">false</value>` inside the CMakeLists.txt.user generated by Qt Creator on the project configuration stage.

#### 2. Test minimal project setup

I've created small conan&cmake app just to test stdout (using std::cout) and spdlog lib from conan. Everything is fine.

#### Some thoughts

I think that something is wrong with my environment variables. Especially, in env I guess I have no paths to installed conan2 shared libs for proper execution.

Does conan2 provide proper solution for this? My research still gives nothing.

Also I expect some Qt 6.4.3 stdout CMake C++20 conflicts.

### Update 1

[image: exit code]

Comment: What's the exit code of the program in the non-working version? If it's `-1073741515` (`0xc0000135`) there's a dll missing from the `PATH` environment variable (or some other location where shared libs are searched for.)

Comment: @fabian yeah it's definitely -1073741515

Comment: It seems the link above "github SageStore" is just pointing to stackoverflow, not to a github project

Comment: Based on the exit errors, it seems that you might be using the dependencies as shared libraries. Conan can generate ``conanrun`` script (.bat or .sh) with environment variables so the shared libraries of dependencies can be found.

Comment: @drodi yeah, lol. Wtf... Why is it pointing to stackoverflow... Anyway I've already fixed the issue. Thank you for your attention

Comment: @drodri unfortunately that bat scripts did not help at all, on linux everything was fine from the very beginning and I was not facing such issue

Comment: It is not clear why the ``conanrun.bat`` is not working, it should definitely contain the PATH env-var defined including the paths to the different shared libraries, so activating it should work. It might be possible that some packages didn't define the ``package_type = "shared-library"`` or had the ``options = {"shared": ..`` defined. It might be worth filing an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that **Conan2** generate shared libs that I don't have path to and bat scripts to setup env `conanrun.bat` for running also does not help. For example, in windows this libs should be in `PATH` to be found (or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for linux).

So, I just configured conan to copy shared libs and it's deps direct to my executables and, as expected, it fixed the issue.